# How do you test PayPal functionality on a customer site as a web developer?

Tags: sandbox

I can't be the only one creating websites for customers that want to use PayPal.  PayPal says that I have to use the customers account to create an account specific sandbox.  Well, I don't want access to the customers account.  I don't want to know their password.  Is there a way to test the PayPal functionality without having direct access to the customers account?

Comment: Can’t you simply create your own account for testing, and switch out the account details with those of the customer later before you set the whole thing live …?

Comment: Review this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

If you're using the classic API, you create 'sandbox accounts' which are basically fake accounts just used for testing.

Comment: If you're using the REST API, you just make requests to the sandbox endpoint: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#api-operations